# Accessing an element in a dictionary using another key

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a dictionary:

```
D = <Queryset[{'name' : 1 , 'id' : 3, 'val': 4}]>
```

D here is list of dictionaries.

I have an object which can fetch me id by using (`s.game_id)`.
By using `s.game_id`, I get '3' as its value, which is correct. However, this object doesn't have `'val'` accessibility. I want to get the corresponding value of `'val'` using `'id'`. But, I am unable to do so and stucked.

***Update 1:***

When I want to have the value of 'name' using 'val'. Then I am unable to do so.

```
game = Game.objects.get(id = touidatelabels.values_list("name", flat = True).get(val = '4'))
```

Comment: Can you provide full snippet? I mean where you want to perform this operation?

Comment: Here `D` is not a dictionary, I think it is a queryset object and it is retrieved through Django's ORM.

Comment: what is `day_slots` in your code? @Timshrok

Comment: then what is D? and day_slots and D are same or related? @Timshrok

Comment: Thanks @MehaParekh. The solution below works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a queryset, you can filter it further and get the results

```
D.values_list("val", flat=True).get(id=s.game_id)
```

But if you prefer to do it without the queryset (maybe just a list of dicts) you can use `next`

```
try:
    next(d["val"] for d in D if d["id"] == s.game_id)
except StopIteration:
    # no item matching the id
    return None # or any other default value or raise an exception
```

Comment: hi @Resley Rodrigues can you please check for update 1 as well?

Comment: @Timshrok this probably doesn't work coz id is an int and does not match the name you pass it. Make sure you're filtering by the correct data